# Setting up CI/CD Pipeline on Azure for Azure Python Function

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build a CI/CD pipeline for a Azure Python Function using Azure DevOps Pipeline. I am mainly trying to follow the following tutorial: https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-build-ci-cd-for-python-azure-functions-using-azure-devops-7087a76e535b

But an issue that I have is that within the same repository, I have codes for multiple Azure Functions. For example,

```
| - app 
| - microservices
|    | - azure_func1
|    | - azure_func2
|    | - azure_func3
|    | - azure_func4
```

Within each Azure Function folder, I have the necessary files (e.g. host.json, proxies.json, requirements.txt etc.). When setting up the Pipeline, I can't seem to find a field that allows me to specify which directory should the Build pipeline take the code from and build into Azure Artifacts.

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

Azure function App has multiple configurations to manage the function app instance which will apply to all the functions, here host.json is the metadata file where all these configurations are placed.

Configurations in host.json related to bindings are applied equally to each function in the function app.

In host.json we can specify number of functions which can apply the settings, so that only these functions will be considered for specific configurations. If this array is empty, then this will be applied for whole function in function app.

```
{
    "functions": [ "function1", "function2" ]
}
```

Below is the sample host.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "aggregator": {
        "batchSize": 1000,
        "flushTimeout": "00:00:30"
    },
    "extensions": {
        "blobs": {},
        "cosmosDb": {},
        "durableTask": {},
        "eventHubs": {},
        "http": {},
        "queues": {},
        "sendGrid": {},
        "serviceBus": {}
    },
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
    },
    "functions": [ "QueueProcessor", "GitHubWebHook" ],
    "functionTimeout": "00:05:00",
    "healthMonitor": {
        "enabled": true,
        "healthCheckInterval": "00:00:10",
        "healthCheckWindow": "00:02:00",
        "healthCheckThreshold": 6,
        "counterThreshold": 0.80
    },
    "logging": {
        "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
        "logLevel": {
          "Function.MyFunction": "Information",
          "default": "None"
        },
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
              "isEnabled": true,
              "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 20,
              "evaluationInterval": "01:00:00",
              "initialSamplingPercentage": 100.0, 
              "samplingPercentageIncreaseTimeout" : "00:00:01",
              "samplingPercentageDecreaseTimeout" : "00:00:01",
              "minSamplingPercentage": 0.1,
              "maxSamplingPercentage": 100.0,
              "movingAverageRatio": 1.0,
              "excludedTypes" : "Dependency;Event",
              "includedTypes" : "PageView;Trace"
            },
            "enableLiveMetrics": true,
            "enableDependencyTracking": true,
            "enablePerformanceCountersCollection": true,            
            "httpAutoCollectionOptions": {
                "enableHttpTriggerExtendedInfoCollection": true,
                "enableW3CDistributedTracing": true,
                "enableResponseHeaderInjection": true
            },
            "snapshotConfiguration": {
                "agentEndpoint": null,
                "captureSnapshotMemoryWeight": 0.5,
                "failedRequestLimit": 3,
                "handleUntrackedExceptions": true,
                "isEnabled": true,
                "isEnabledInDeveloperMode": false,
                "isEnabledWhenProfiling": true,
                "isExceptionSnappointsEnabled": false,
                "isLowPrioritySnapshotUploader": true,
                "maximumCollectionPlanSize": 50,
                "maximumSnapshotsRequired": 3,
                "problemCounterResetInterval": "24:00:00",
                "provideAnonymousTelemetry": true,
                "reconnectInterval": "00:15:00",
                "shadowCopyFolder": null,
                "shareUploaderProcess": true,
                "snapshotInLowPriorityThread": true,
                "snapshotsPerDayLimit": 30,
                "snapshotsPerTenMinutesLimit": 1,
                "tempFolder": null,
                "thresholdForSnapshotting": 1,
                "uploaderProxy": null
            }
        }
    },
    "managedDependency": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "retry": {
      "strategy": "fixedDelay",
      "maxRetryCount": 5,
      "delayInterval": "00:00:05"
    },
    "singleton": {
      "lockPeriod": "00:00:15",
      "listenerLockPeriod": "00:01:00",
      "listenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00",
      "lockAcquisitionTimeout": "00:01:00",
      "lockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:03"
    },
    "watchDirectories": [ "Shared", "Test" ],
    "watchFiles": [ "myFile.txt" ]
}
```

Also if we would like to disable a function from not to trigger according to your requirement we can add the value `"AzureWebJobs.HttpExample.Disabled": true` in our local.settings.json.

Sample as below:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true", 
    "AzureWebJobs.HttpExample.Disabled": true
  }
}
```

For more info refer to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function?tabs=portal)